# take picture with Tablet it's rotated following the camera position

Tags: android, image, odoo-11

This app have the possibility to take picture and store it on tablet.
I have some problem because this app use the Odoo framework and i don't know if it's a problem of that framework or something that i miss on Android code.

The problem is that when i take a picture, the image is good only if i take it with tablet landscape and with home button to the right.
If i change rotation and take picture, the image is rotated...
For example if i take picture with landscape orientation and home button to the left the image is upside down...
If i take it portrait the image is rotated by 90°....

The Android request image don't manage rotation of image related to rotation of the device?
Because if yes...it's a problem related to the odoo framework...if not i need to manage it.

EDIT___

We resize the image and use the Base64 for store and synchronize data with odoo when the phone is offline too.

onActivityResult()

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() method");

    OValues response = fileManager.handleResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (response != null) {
        projectIssueImage = new ProjectIssueImage(this, null);
        OValues values = new OValues();

        String imageBase64 = BitmapUtils.uriToBase64(Uri.parse(response.getString("file_uri")), getContentResolver(), false);
        byte[] decodedImage = Base64.decode(imageBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedImage, 0, decodedImage.length);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleDown(bitmapImage, 1000, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOS);

        values.put("image", Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        values.put("file_name", response.get("datas_fname"));
        values.put("file_type", response.get("file_type"));
        values.put("issue_id", currentObject);
        int _id = projectIssueImage.insert(values);
    }
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("id", currentObject);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Code that resize image

```
public static Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize,
                               boolean filter) {
    float ratio = Math.min(
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getHeight());

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width, height, filter);

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Comment: How are you viewing the images? Typically, cameras will save CPU/memory by shooting every image in the sensor's "native" rotation and storing rotation data with the images (e.g. in JPEG EXIF data.) Some viewing methods will respect the rotation metadata, and some won't.

Comment: You can change image rotation when image capured by programmatically as you want. because worked on it and got success in this.

Comment: @MattGibson It's not a viewing method the problem (i think) because when the image is loaded on odoo by synch is rotated too.
There is something from picture take and store it that change the rotation of it.

It's possible that the method scaleDown generate a new image rotated?

Code edited.

Comment: @SandeepParish if i change rotation the function is static...i need to know image orientation after rotate it, because if i rotate it always by 90° i'm at the start point :)

Comment: first load your image on a imageview and check image rotaion and change image angle programmatically as per your requirements.

Comment: @SandeepParish it's possible to check image rotation?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this if it helps.

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            }

            Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
            Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }
```